# How to pass proper datatype to class using Numba?

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html) to make my code execute faster. However, the code throws the following error:

```
This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: Unsupported array dtype: object
- argument 1: Unsupported array dtype: object
```

I have a class written is some manner:

```
spec = [
    ('train_x', float64[:,:]),
    ('train_y', float64[:]),
    ('test_x', float64[:,:]),
    ('test_y', float64[:]),
]

@jitclass(spec)
class num_features:
    def __init__(self, train_x,  test_x, train_y, test_y):
        self.train_x, self.train_y = train_x, train_y
        self.test_x, self.test_y = test_x, test_y
        self.X_train, self.Y_train = [] , []
        self.X_test, self.Y_test = [] , []

    @property
    def extract_stats(self, matrix):
    ...
```

I'm calling the class like

```
obj = num_features(train_x.to_numpy(), test_x.to_numpy(), train_y, test_y)
```

train_x and test_x are pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several thing going wrong in your code.  First, you cannot use regular python lists in a numba-class, all attributes need to be typed.  You will need to both specify the attributes as `ListTypes` and assign them a type they will contain, such as `float64`.

Second, the actual error you are seeing is because you are trying to pass an in `train_x` and `test_x` as numpy arrays that contain data that is NOT a `float64`.  That is what the error "`Unsupported array dtype: object`" is telling you: your arrays for argument 0 and argument 1 are object arrays, or arrays of python objects.

When you convert them to numpy arrays, pass a `dtype`.

Also, don't get fancy with tuple assignments, numba is finicky enough, just put them one per line.

```
from numba import jitclass, float64, typed, types

spec = [
    ('train_x', float64[:,:]),
    ('train_y', float64[:]),
    ('test_x', float64[:,:]),
    ('test_y', float64[:]),
    ('X_train', types.ListType(types.float64)),
    ('Y_train', types.ListType(types.float64)),
    ('X_test', types.ListType(types.float64)),
    ('Y_test', types.ListType(types.float64))
]

@jitclass(spec)
class num_features:
    def __init__(self, train_x,  test_x, train_y, test_y):
        self.train_x = train_x
        self.train_y = train_y
        self.test_x = test_x
        self.test_y = test_y
        self.X_train = typed.List.empty_list(types.float64)
        self.Y_train = typed.List.empty_list(types.float64)
        self.X_test = typed.List.empty_list(types.float64)
        self.Y_test = typed.List.empty_list(types.float64)

    @property
    def extract_stats(self, matrix):
    ...
```

Now to actually call the class, you need to pass in `float64` arrays.  You can use:

```py
obj = num_features(train_x.to_numpy(np.float64),
                   test_x.to_numpy(np.float64),
                   train_y.astype(np.float64),
                   test_y.astype(np.float64))
```

Comment: Nicely explained! However, I have a dataset that is holding a pandas series inside a cell of a dataframe, but that is out of context of above question.